# Racket Append Undesired Reversal of List

Tags: scheme, racket

I wrote a small function that takes a list and returns a list composed of only positive numbers. This all works fine, but for some reason, it is reversing the order. More information below on that. Could someone please tell me if this is normal, or if I miss-wrote something? Thank you in advance.

```
(define (positive-nums-only lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (append (positive-nums-only (cdr lst))
              (if (>= (car lst) 0)
                  (list (car lst))
                  '()))))
(positive-nums-only '(1 2 -4 90 -4))
```

The above test case returns '(90 2 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reversing the append?

```
(define (positive-nums-only lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (append (if (>= (car lst) 0) (list (car lst)) '())
              (positive-nums-only (cdr lst)))))
```

Personally I find it more natural to write it like this:

```
(define (positive-nums-only lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      '()
      (let ((rest (positive-nums-only (cdr lst))))
        (if (>= (car lst) 0)
            (cons (car lst) rest)
            rest))))
```

Comment: @aurora91 no problem, see edit for another way using `let` and `cons`

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to test it out and play around with it!

Answer (score 3):

You did not make a mistake, the program is making what you asked.

See, the program finishes the recursion calls first, before going into resolving the `if` statement. This causes the `(list ... )` to start listing from the last element that is positive, in this example it will be `90`.

Changing the code order will produce the result you want.

```
(define (positive-nums-only lst)
(if (empty? lst) '()
  (append (if (>= (car lst) 0 )
             (list (car lst))
             '())
          (positive-nums-only (cdr lst)))
)
)
```

On the other hand, this kind of recursion could be expensive to the computer. I'd use tail recursion, like this:

```
  (define positive-nums-only-tail
  (λ (lst r)
    (cond ((empty? lst) (reverse r))
          ((positive? (car lst))
           (positive-nums-only-tail (cdr lst)
                                    (cons (car lst) r)))
          (else (positive-nums-only-tail (cdr lst) r))
          )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the tail recursion solution! We just covered it in my class today, so this will be a great reference for me to follow on future assignments.

Comment: Your second paragraph is a bit confusing; `(append x y)` puts `x` in front of `y` regardless of which is evaluated first.

Comment: @Molbdnilo Yes, and that's why it adds the element that is evaluating if it passes trough instead of leaving it until the recursion finishes.

Comment: @DavidMerinos I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you mean. It sounds like you think that the value of `(if (>= (car lst) 0) (list (car lst)) '())` depends on whether the recursive call is evaluated before or after it, but that would contradict your agreeing with me.

Comment: The `(foldr cons (list (car lst)) r)` goes through and generate a new list at every iteration. I bet it's probably slower than `append`. Wouldn't it be better to just `cons` to the front and do just one `reverse` in the end instead?

Comment: You are right Sylwester, I'm still a bit confused about the proper use of `append`, `cons` and `foldr` / `foldl`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not the value but the place it occupies later.